# Search string in JSON values without the key

Tags: python, json

Is it possible to search through a JSON and find a single string?
I just want to know if this sting is in the JSON or not.

What I have tried before:

```
def parse_string(self, reg_string,  input_data):
        self.logger.info("parse string")
        for i in input_data:
            self.logger.info(input_data[i])
            if input_data[i] == reg_string:
                return (input_data[i])
            else:
                self.logger.info('regex: %s not found', reg_string)
```

but it prints lots of `None`s.

My JSON:

```
{
  "id": 5931,
  "state": "opened",
  "created_at": "2020-09-24T15:04:05.728+02:00",
  "author": {
    "id": 130,
    "username": "veeti",
    "state": "active"
  }
```

How I call the method:

```
parser.parse_string("veeti", parser.data)
```

Comment: `str(json_value).find("veeti") > -1` didn't work?

Comment: Does it matter if it's one of the values or can it be one of the keys? Do you want too look inside lists as well or only dictionaries?

Comment: @senthilbalaji your solution worked! if you want you can create an answer. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do `str(json_value).find("veeti") > -1`

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below

```
def find_item(obj, look_for):
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            return find_item(v, look_for)
        else:
            if v == look_for:
                return True
    return False


data = {
  "id": 5931,
  "iid": 4145,
  "project_id": 57,
  "title": "Change: SELAP-3333, SFCAP-3139",
  "state": "opened",
  "created_at": "2020-09-24T15:04:05.728+02:00",
  "updated_at": "2020-09-24T15:04:09.903+02:00",
  "author": {
    "id": 130,
    "username": "veeti",
    "state": "active"
  }
}

print(find_item(data,'veeti'))
print(find_item(data,'not_veeti'))
```

output

```
True
False
```